# avoid consistently fetching data when clicking an a tab

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, quora

I am developing an ionic app which allow every user to see all his places and the places he's invited to, provided he clicks on the "My Places" tab. The problem is whenever I open the tab I have to refresh the data by calling API. What I tried to do is to trigger the scope responsible for fetching the data every time he add a place, delete a place, or he's invited to a place. For example, if he add a place, I emit this `$rootScope.$emit("RefreshPlaces", {});` and in "My Places" controller I have

```
$rootScope.$on('RefreshPlaces', function() {
  $scope.getPlaces();
});
```

The problem I encountered is that "My places" controller sometimes isn't loaded and thus don't receive the event and we see nothing on "My places" tab ( empty page ).
The reason I did all that is because the app become slow and it makes no sense to fetch data every time a user click on the tab.

Furthermore, I noticed while using Facebook and Quora that the naviguation between tabs don't always fetch data from server.How does Quora or Facebook knows when to fetch data and when not ?

Comment: Is your tab which displays the places always visible to the user?

Comment: It makes complete sense to fetch the data from the API every time user opens the tab. This way you'll always display the most updated data. Also, fetching the data from API every time he modifies it is of no use, as the data is not visible to the user.

Comment: @PrerakSola Yes. it's an ion-tab.

Comment: @PrerakSola Well, it's not like data is changing regularly.  It don't seem right to load the server. Plus, I am able to detect when places are being changed. What I would like is that my controller fetch data when the app run for the first time or when is not in the background anymore. Any ideas how can I manage to load it without constantly calling the server ?

Comment: If not from server, from where do you want to load the data?

Comment: The data is loaded from the server. I just don't want it to be uploaded each and every time he clicks on tabs since most likely the data won't be changed.